# Optimize string checking function for pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe which has a date column which should be of the format '2016-01-17'.

Occasionally the dates are junk and may look something like '0-1274753-3', and I'd like to remove these rows.

My attempt has basically been to define a function to check if a string is a date and then apply this across every entry in the column, throwing out rows that fail. This is a slow process across a large dataframe and I'm hoping to find a better solution.

The current attempt looks like:

```
from dateutil.parser import parse

def is_date (string):
    try:
         parse (string)
         return True
    except ValueError:
         return False

df = df [df.datecol.apply(is_date)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`errors='coerce'`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) to convert invalid date strings to NaN. Then use [`dropna()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) to drop rows with `NaN` values:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'datecol':['2016-01-17', '0-1274753-3']})
df['datecol'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datecol'], errors='coerce')
# this drops all rows which contain NaN
df = df.dropna(axis=0, how='any')
# alternatively, use this to drop all rows which contain NaN in the datecol column
# df = df.loc[pd.notnull(df['datecol'])]
print(df)
```

yields

```
     datecol
0 2016-01-17
```